# How to update multiple ranges of records where the ranges are defined by subqueries?

Tags: mysql

In order to update records with a range of values I am aware of using the `BETWEEN` operator e.g.

```
UPDATE datetable 
   SET tableflag = 1 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-03-01'
```

will set the field 'tableflag' to 1 for every record where the date lies between the 1st of February 2017 and the 1st of March 2017. This is a simple way for handling a single or multiple fixed ranges (by using several or conditions betwee `BETWEEN` operators).

For a dynamic range e.g. set 'tableflag' to 1 for every record where the date is between the first and last Sunday in February for the year 2017, one can use a subquery to generate the dates for the first and last Sundays in February.

However if the condition in the above problem is generalized and one needs to set 'tableflag' to 1 for every record where the date is between the first and last Sunday in February, regardless of year, the problem becomes quite a bit more complicated. The between operator appears to require a single row and passing it two equally dimensioned subqueries throws an error (1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row).

Any idea how I can solve the generalized problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing complex patterns where the dates aren't consecutive dates within a range, but a set of individual dates.

If you need a pattern of specific dates, I would use the `IN()` predicate instead of `BETWEEN`.

It would be awkward to generate a complex pattern of dates in SQL, so use a client application with access to a robust date library. Generate a list of desired dates with more convenient methods, then use that list in an `IN()` predicate in SQL.